# Inserting data into Greenplum Physical table

Tags: hadoop, hive, greenplum

I am trying to insert data from Greenplum external table to a physical (or normal table) table. The external table is pointing to a hive file which ahs around 132 million of data. But, when my external table shows only a count of 66 million. As a result, when inserted into a physical table i have only 66 million records inserted. Why is it so? Is there anything to do with table properties of my external table? if so how?

Comment: Please show the commands  you use to determine the size of the file, size of the table and the command to go from file to table.

Comment: Are you sure the Hive table has 132 million records?  Hive will use the metadata to determine the number of rows in a table when it sees a count(*) query instead of actually counting the rows.  I would analyze your Hive table and then do a count(\*) again to make sure.

Comment: The other thing to look for is poorly formatted rows.  Hive will let you stick anything into a table without an error where GPDB won't.  You can look at the "bad" rows too.  Check out the documentation: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/admin_guide/load/topics/g-viewing-bad-rows-in-the-error-table-or-error-log.html

Comment: @JonRoberts Thanks for the hint. Looks like the issue is with the hive file. when i query my hive table, it shows the count of 132 million, but when verified again at the file level i could see 36 million which is prettey weird. The below is the command i used to check the count of file.
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://DLDEVELOPMENT/data/wcdl/new/database_1/gpsample_table_test/* | wc -l

Comment: In Hive, run this: "ANALYZE TABLE table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;" and then run "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;"  Hive should show the correct count after the statistics have been updated.

Answer (score 1):

When counted via hive you see 66 million records. Assuming you just did a `count(*)` that should be straigtforward enough.

Now you are not happy with this as you have 132 million 'data', which happens to be exactly twice as much.

I would not worry about any setting that only lets you load in the first 66 million records, so lets look at the likely suspects.

1. Two 'data' (lines?) correspond to one record.
2. There is something weird in the data, that makes you miss half the records when you evaluate it as a table. (Perhaps a break after 66 million lines, perhaps weird line endings)
3. You did not actually load in all your input files

Carefull inspection should point you towards the actual culprit. In case you don't know where to start:

1. Look at the first and last few lines in the file, and compare their full contents to the first and last few records in the table
2. Check whether the lines from each input file are represented in the output
3. If you are sure some data is missing, try to reason which line from the input files should be missing, and see whether you can locate it in the table.

Comment: I dont think it is the issue with the double data. I face the same problem for the table with 100 million data. When i try to insert the data from external table having 100 miliion rows to a normal table. I see only 66 million getting inserted.

Comment: @SriBharath What happens when you only try to insert 10 'data'? And what happens if you actually duplicate your input file and try to insert 264 million?

Comment: When i insert 10, i have no issues. Similarly, Data insert works perfect with 10 million data. Any amount of data which is greater than 66 million is not getting inserted. The same is with 264 million data. When my file is duplciated to 264 million, and is tried to insert into my external table,  i see only 66 million inserted.

Comment: @SriBharath That is quite surprising. Depending on how you split and duplicated your data it could still be possible that there is something 'weird' in the data that stops the load. Assuming your table has exactly N rows after reading, could you inspect line N-1 till N+2 in the raw data? -- As workaround you could perhaps split your data into parts of less than 66 million and then union them. Or you could try to load in the file as textfile with pig. -- For what it is worth: I have used external tables of more than 66M rows before so that is at least not a simple constraint.

Comment: Just had an analysis of my hive file. Looks like some issue with this file. When i query my table it shows 132 million but when looked into the file with wc -l option i could see only 36 million. Any idea what's causing this disruption?

Comment: @SriBharath Not sure, but if you think the problem is in the file (and not the act of using it as an external table) then I would say that is a different issue. If you can't figure it out you could consider asking a new question, make sure to include the relevant information (including what exactly you query, and what exactly you wordcount and how exactly you query)

Answer (score 0):

Is your hive table partitioned

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why does this limit exist?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/214174/18)

Answer (score 0):

Finally! The issue seems to be fixed. I continued my research regarding this and the issue seems to be w.r.t data redundancy. (As suggested by dennis in previous answer). The table was having duplicate values ( duplicated on all the columns). Each record had another set of 11 duplicate records (which is acceptable though in my case). In order to avoid the redundancy, I added one more column which could act as a primary key ( an auto generated surrogate key). Now, when i tried to load the greenplum physical table from an external table, I could see all the 132 million records inserted without any issues.

However, though my issue is solved, for a deeper analysis, the question still remains about the threshold value (66 million records). A new question will be posted on this.